# have an array of struct in wsdl + php without using NSoap

Tags: php, wsdl

I want to have an array of struct (an array of books with their specifications like publication, ISBN number, ...). in wsdl and php. I have searched a little and I have found files that uses Nusoap, However, I dont want to use NuSoap. Is there any solution? I would appreciate if you help me in writing the related wsdl, client and server (php) files.

Thank you so much.

Best, shadi.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP client and server can be written using PHP's [SOAP Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php), but as of now it doesn't create the WSDL for you (a.k.a. you can write it by hand but it would be a pain in the a$$). I would consider using nuSoap if you need a WSDL generated.

Why don't you want to use nuSoap?

Comment: Thank you very much.

I viewed that link. does it contain an example about having "array of struct"? 
I do not want to use NuSoup because it's new for me and I do not have enough tome to learn it if it is complex.

Best,
Shadi.

Comment: nuSoap is not very complex, I've used it in a project and I was able to get started fairly quickly. If you would have to learn PHP's Soap extension anyway, I would recommend just using nuSoap. You can find some great tutorials online.